# Traversing a directory using Makefile

Tags: linux, bash, unix, makefile, automation

I am making use of a makefile to traverse a directory , store the file names in a variable , extract the file number using regex and print the file number .

Below is the code block I am using :

```
1. set -e ;\
2. for file in $$(MY_HOME)/mydir/python_files/ ;\
3. do \
4. string =$${file} ;\
5. [[ $$string =~ .*clause([0-9]*).py ]] ;\ 
6. file_num=$${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ; \
7. python $$(My_Home)/base_py_<file_num>.py ;\
8. done ;\
```

LINE 7 is the command in makefile I want to include in the for loop. I want the actual file_num in the above < file_num > placeholder (line 7). How can I do the same. Is there any alternative approach for the same ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you allowed to code some Python script to do that work? a `Makefile` can run a Python script (and some Python script could run `make`). Read the documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and of [Python](http://python.org/)

Comment: Read also [*Recursive make considered harmful*](https://accu.org/journals/overload/14/71/miller_2004/). If allowed, consider using [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) or write your C program using [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) and other [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). See also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and the documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: I am a beginner to this. Just want to clarify can we run some commands of makefile in a for loop like shown above?

Comment: Also, please provide some [mre] - your code chunk is not one. Are you allowed to use [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/) ? Are you allowed to read their documentation, download their source code, and study it (they all are [open source software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software)...). Of course, **there are *several* alternative approaches** to solve your problem (which is not clear)

Comment: Thank you @BasileStarynkevitch . I will definitely keep in mind , your suggestions for my future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a native `make` approach instead of looping in bash, like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
MY_HOME := myhome
CLAUSE_FILES_DIR := $(MY_HOME)/mydir/python_files

clause_files := $(wildcard $(CLAUSE_FILES_DIR)/*clause*.py)
clause_numbers := $(foreach clause_file,$(notdir $(clause_files:.py=)), \
                    $(lastword $(subst clause, ,$(clause_file))))

.PHONY: execute-clause-%
execute-clause-%: $(MY_HOME)/base_py_%.py $(CLAUSE_FILES_DIR)/*clause%.py
        echo python $<

all: $(addprefix execute-clause-,$(clause_numbers))
```

`clause_files` will keep all existing files matching the pattern. `clause_numbers` will process the file names by stripping extension and directory, then split on *clause* to get only the part between *clause* and extension.

`execute-clause-%` is a generic rule to run based on existence of a specific *base_py_*.py* script and a matching *clause* file. If one or the other does not exist, the rule will not be run.

Finally `all` rule executes all existing clauses. And since every processing is done by a separate rule, all of them might be executed in parallel by just running `make -j`.

Sample output:

```
## Preparation stage
$ mkdir -p myhome/mydir/python_files
$ for i in `seq 1 5`; do touch myhome/base_py_$i.py; done
$ for i in `seq 1 5`; do touch myhome/mydir/python_files/${RANDOM}_clause$i.py; done
$ touch myhome/mydir/python_files/foo.py  # Just to show it does not match
$ touch myhome/base_py_100.py             # To demonstrate missing clause file

$ ls -R myhome/
myhome/:
base_py_1.py  base_py_100.py  base_py_2.py  base_py_3.py  base_py_4.py  base_py_5.py  mydir

myhome/mydir:
python_files

myhome/mydir/python_files:
14363_clause1.py  31198_clause2.py  4514_clause5.py  4767_clause4.py  7812_clause3.py  foo.py

## Execution
$ make -s
python myhome/base_py_3.py
python myhome/base_py_2.py
python myhome/base_py_5.py
python myhome/base_py_4.py
python myhome/base_py_1.py
```

Note that neither `foo.py` nor `base_py_100.py` did not cause running the rule.

Comment: Thanks you so much @rapsy . This indeed helped me a lot. Can you please provide me your email where I can contact you ?